# Hiding class visibility C++

Tags: c++

I'm creating a game engine, I've got a lot of different classes.
My engine and game are in the same project.

Some classes should be used only by my game engine, not by game.

Can I hide some classes to make them accessible only for Engine classes?

@Edit

I'm including engine.h in my game class, and engine.h is including other classes that I want to hide from game.

Comment: What's wrong with only including the headers that define the Engine-only classes in the Engine implementation files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of different approaches so here is one of them how to solve that.

**Private constructor**

By making the constructor of `Foo` private you can ensure that just the `friend` classes can allocate instances of the object. This approach complains already at compile-time. One disadvantage is that you have to list all classes that are allowed to create instances of `Foo`. In case we are talking about a few classes this would be a proper way to go with.

```
class Foo
{
private:
  Foo() {}
  friend class Engine;
};

class Engine
{
    Foo f; // OK
};

class ForeignClass
{
    Foo f; // FAILED to create
};

void main()
{
    Foo f; // FAILED to create
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include the headers then they won't be 'visible'. So only include the headers of the class you want to use.

Comment: I'm including engine.h in my game class, and engine.h is including other classes that I want to hide from game.

Comment: so use forward declarations + include these classes only in the relevant engine CPP files.

Comment: I forgot about including in CPP files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When developing a Game Engine project there is considerable thought to its design process. One of the most important goals is to design this project to be as modular and reusable as possible. All of your Engine's components should be in their own project and all Game content should be in its own project as well. This way you can reuse the Game Engine project to create multiple games only by creating a new Game Project. This way you do not have to strip out Game Source Code from within the Engine itself and breaking the engine. This saves a lot of time, work and trouble in the future. Consider this Design Pattern. The project design flow that I am showing you below is using the OpenGL API.

**Engine Project**: A static lib that contains all the classes that are required for loading images, sounds, processing shaders, rendering objects to the screen and handling networking.

- Engine: This class will be abstract and it will create your window, setup up the game resolution and initialize either DirectX or OpenGL or any other Graphics API. Your Game class that is located in its own project will inherit from this.
- AssetStorage: Class that manages the memory of all assets.
- Batch: A class that creates a types of batches of triangle strips, fans etc. to be use to send vertices to the video card.
- BatchManager: Class that manages batches.
- CommonStructs: Header only file that contains structs & enums that are commonaly used throughout multiple classes within the engine.
- ExceptionHandler: A Class that handles all exceptions.
- FontManager: A Class that manages fonts which are loaded from texture files.
- Logger: A class that will log either to a File or the Console when either an Error, Warning or an important message needs to be displayed or logged.
- Settings: A class that stores user settings, such as resolution, mouse sensitivity etc.
- Singleton: An abstract base class that is used to make sure specific classes can only exist once per running of application. Examples, any Manger Class Types, Engine::Game are a type of a Singleton object.
- Utility: A class that is not an object but contains many useful functions which are defined as being static. To use one of such you would include the *.h file and call any method as in `Utility::convertToUnsigned( string );`
- Animation: An abstract class that all animation types will derive from.
- AnimationGuiMover: A type of animation responsible for moving Gui objects.
- AnimationManager: A manager class that manages all animations.
- AnimationTimer: A type of animation object that is based on a set timer.
- FileHandler: Base class that specific file handler types will derive from
- MkoFileReader: Reading in a user defined 2D or 3D object.
- TextFileReader: Reading in a text file.
- TextFileWriter: Writing to a Text file.
- TextureFileReader: Reading in texture file: png, tga, bmp, jpeg, etc.
- Array2d: An Mko object type.
- BaseMko: Base class for Mko objects.
- FontFile: A 2D image file to create Fonts.
- Image2D: Another Mko object type.
- Surface3d: Another Mko object type
- VisualMko: Any Mko object that has visual rendering associates such as a sprite or 3D model.
- ShaderManager: A manager class that handles all shaders.
- ShaderProgramSettings: Used to set OpenGL Shader Programs according to attributes and uniforms - relies heavily on templates.
- ShaderVariable: This can either be an attribute or uniform and relies heavily on templates.
- BlockProcess: Class used to block a process: Such that we only want 1 instance of the game running, so within windows it will create a mutex based off of the windows handle and application name, preventing multiple executions of this application.
- BlockThread: Used to create and destroy critical sections when working with multithreading.
- OpenglThread: A specific thread class used to work with OpenGL
- VolatileLocker: Similar to BlockThread but used with volatile data types.
- **Gui System:** *This is a hierarchy of classes; some which are abstract base classes*
- GuiCompositeElement: Abstract Base Class
- GuiElement: Abstract Base Class
- GuiImage: Inherits from GuiRenderable
- GuiImageElement: Does not inherit from any other class.
- GuiLabel: Inherits from GuiText
- GuiLayout: Abstract Base Class for All Layout Types - Inherits from GuiRenderable
- GuiLayoutAbsolute: Inherits from GuiLayout
- GuiLayoutGrid: Inherits from GuiLayout
- GuiLayoutSlices: Inherits from GuiLayout
- GuiLayoutStack: Inherits from GuiLayout
- GuiLoader: A class that reads in a gui text file parses the data and constructs all gui objects to reduce build times when changing data within the gui system.
- GuiRenderable: Inherits from GuiCompositeElement but is also an abstract base class
- GuiScreen: Can not be a child of another Gui Type But contains Gui children - inherits from GuiCompositeElement
- GuiText: Inherits from GuiRenderable
- GuiTextArea: Inherits from GuiText
- **More To Come:** *Objects such as sound processing, networking etc.*

**Game Project**: Contains game only content such as which assets to load, loading levels, how to handle user input from keyboard mouse etc., and anything that is specific to this game.

- main.cpp - Main Entry Point.
- Game: Game Class that starts the game loop, initializes all settings, constructs all necessary objects etc., and handles user input.
- GameState: Switching between playing, pausing, etc. A state machine.
- Property: Properties that are specific to this game.
- **More To Come**: *This project is far from finished*

As you can see this is designed with the idea of the Game Engine being as generic and modular as possible in order to separate all Game Logic from Engine Logic. With this type of design process, all one needs to do to build a completely different game using the same existing engine is to remove the Game project and add a new one, store all of the assets in their appropriate directories and write the necessary code for the new game. This way one doesn't have to worry about diving into the Engine project hunting through thousands of lines of code trying to determine what is Engine code and what is Game Code with the high possibility of breaking the engine. This kind of design flow will save many future headaches, and precious time.

As you can see the Engine class is responsible for the creation of the Window, Setting up the Graphics API, creating the Manager Objects and the ability to load in and render resources. With this Engine class being abstract a Game class must inherit from it and having pure virtual methods to handle keyboard & mouse input makes certain that each game must implement how the user controls will be handled. This project has been in development for a couple of years and still more work needs to be done. This solution / game engine is considerably lite weight compared to anything that is of an industrial standard use engine and I am already expanding well over 100,000 lines of code and I haven't even mentioned anything about game logic, scoring, level progression, physics, nor AI.